# Display the character after a white space

Tags: powerbuilder

I am new to PowerBuilder, I have this dropdown list box which displays the names of employees. 
Jerry Casimera Fondrada, Joy Valdez Cortez, Kyle Vincent Korver and Joe Pring. Out from those names, I would like to generate a username using the first letters of their first name together with the last name. Example JCFondera, JVCortez, KVKorver and JPring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string name, namepart, username

integer i, length

name = this.text
length = len(this.text)

for i = 1 to length
    if left(name, 1) = ' ' then 
        username += left(namepart, 1)
        namepart = ''
    else 
        namepart += left(name, 1)
    end if 
    name = right(name, len(name) - 1)
next

username += namepart
```

This is in the selectionchanged event from the drop down listbox.
The string "username" is the output.

Answer (score 1):

Do the names come from a database?  If yes, I advise to use a DropDownDataWindow (DDDW), instead.  In the select you define for the DDDW, use a computed field to let the information appear as you wish. The exact syntax will depend on the DB you use.  Alternatively, use a DDDW and a a computed field. In both cases, no further programming needed.